# Psycopg3 Async Connection pool leakage/timeout problem

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, psycopg3

I have a leakage problem in my Psycopg3 Async Connection pool and I cannot find the source of the problem.

I extended my Flask app such that once the server starts up it creates an Async Connection pool.

Then, whenever a request is made, the app gets the connections needed to retrieve the data from the database, execute the queries, process the results and return the results for the user.

My implementation works for a while, but after few usages, it stops working. The exception thrown is `psycopg_pool.PoolTimeout`.

When I get the pool stats, I see that `pool_available = 0`, while `requests_queued` and `requests_errors` keep increasing at each new try, indicating that the available connections have exhausted.

Can anyone help me find the source of the problem?

Here's the implementation:

1. The reusable connection pool:

```py
# db.py
import os
from psycopg_pool import AsyncConnectionPool

class DB:
    def __init__(self):
        self.async_pool = None

    def connect_async(self):
        conninfo = (f"dbname={os.environ['DBNAME']} "
                    f"user={os.environ['POSTGRES_USER']} "
                    f"password={os.environ['POSTGRES_PASSWORD']} "
                    f"host={os.environ['POSTGRES_HOST']} "
                    f"port={os.environ['POSTGRES_PORT']}")
        self.async_pool = AsyncConnectionPool(
            conninfo, min_size=4, max_size=10, timeout=15)

    def get_async_pool(self):
        if self.async_pool is None:
            self.connect_async()
        return self.async_pool

# extensions.py
from db import DB

my_db = DB()
```

2. The query execution:

```py
# search.py
from extensions import my_db

async def keyword_search(query):
    async with my_db.get_async_pool().connection() as aconn:
        async with aconn.cursor() as cur:
            # query = ...  keyword search logic
            await cur.execute(query)
            documents = await cur.fetchall()
            column_names = [desc[0] for desc in cur.description]
    return [dict(zip(column_names, doc)) for doc in documents]

async def semantic_search(query):
    async with my_db.get_async_pool().connection() as aconn:
        async with aconn.cursor() as cur:
            # query = ...  semantic search logic
            await cur.execute(query)
            documents = await cur.fetchall()
            column_names = [desc[0] for desc in cur.description]
    return [dict(zip(column_names, doc)) for doc in documents]

async def full_search(query):
    ks, ss = await asyncio.gather(keyword_search(query), semantic_search(query))
    return ks + ss
```

3. The Flask app:

```py
from extensions import my_db
from search import full_search

@bp.route('/search', methods=['GET'])
async def search_fn():
    query = request.args.get('query')
    for _ in range(2):
        try:
            results = await full_search(query)
            return jsonify(results)
        except psycopg_pool.PoolTimeout as e:
            stats = my_db.get_async_pool().get_stats()
            app.logger.error({'error': str(e), 'pool_stats': stats})
            
    return jsonify({'error': 'Database connection timeout'}), 500
```

Other info that might be relevant:

- The only async route in the application is the `search_fn` above; all others are sync.

Thanks in advance!